# How can we interpret $\frac{df}{dx}(x - \Delta x)\le f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We have a continuous function $f(x)$.

After some calculations, we came to know that $f(x−\Delta x)−f(x)\ge\Delta xf(x)$.

Now if we do some rearrangement
\begin{align}
&f(x - \Delta x) - f(x) \ge\Delta xf(x) \\
&f(x) - f(x - \Delta x) \le -\Delta xf(x) \\
&\frac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x} \le -f(x)
\end{align}
Taking the limit
$$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x} = \frac{df}{dx}(x - \Delta x)\le -f(x)$$
But what does $\frac{df}{dx}(x - \Delta x)\le -f(x)$ mean? Can someone please help me understand it?

I mean it's not a functional differential equation. It's not even an equation. Can we even interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "$\frac{df}{dx}(x - \Delta x)\le f(x)$" means is that you haven't figured out dummy variables yet. In the expression $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$

$\Delta x$ is a dummy variable. It is defined by the notation, and its definition does not extend beyond that expression. This is built into the meaning of $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}$. This breaks $\Delta x$ from whatever meaning it had before (which you didn't actually explain). Because the $\lim$ notation requires a dummy variable, the use of a previously introduced variable is basically saying "I'm done with the previous meaning of $\Delta x$ now. Here is a new meaning for this symbol." But like all dummy variables, that new meaning ends with the end of the notation.
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$ depends on the value of $x$ and on the function $f$. It does not depend on a value for $\Delta x$, which exists in it only as a notational convenience.

So when you say $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x} = \frac{df}{dx}(x - \Delta x)$, that doesn't make sense. There isn't any dependence on $\Delta x$ on the left hand side. How can the right hand side depend on it?

In truth $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x} = \frac{df}{dx}(x)$$
To see this, substitute $-h$ for $\Delta x$. Then $h \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$, though from the other side. And vice versa. But the notation $\Delta x \to 0$ means it approaches from both sides, not just one, so that change makes no difference. With the substitution, the limit becomes
$$\lim_{-h \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x + h)}{-h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{df}{dx}(x)$$

Comment: Thank you. I have studied your answer and if I understood what $\Delta x$ really is, for $x\ge 0$, $f(x−\Delta x)−f(x)\ge\Delta xf(x)$ is equivalent to $\frac{df}{dx}(x)\le -f(x)$? Did I understand it properly?

Comment: "equivalent to?" No. "Implies", yes (assuming that $f$ is differentiable at $x$, and the inequality holds for all real numbers $\Delta x$ in some neighborhood of $0$). $\frac{df}{dx}(x) \le -f(x)$ speaks to the behavior of $f$ in the immediate vicinity of $x$. However, that "immediate vicinity" can be very, very small. Much smaller than any given $\Delta x \ne 0$. $f(x - \Delta x) - f(x) \ge \Delta xf(x)$ specifies the behavior of $f$ at some distance from $x$, not just in the immediate vicinity.